# My Custom Authorize Attribute Always Redirects to Un authroized page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity-3

I am writing custom authorize attribute for one requirement.

As per the requirement, I need to pass all the allowed roles for that particular action method like below.

```
    [MyAuthorize("Admin,Reviewer")]
    public ActionResult GetFXSelldownSummaryData()
    {
        var model = (new FXSelldownSummaryBLL()).GetFXSelldownSummaryData();
        return View(model);
    }
```

When the user logs in, the logged in user role should be compared against all the allowed roles (in the above code, all the allowed roles are `Admin`, and `Reviewer`). If the role matches, the user can see the view, otherwise the page should be navigated to Un authorized page.

I have wrriten the custom attribute like below, everything is working fine but I am ending up with Unauthorized access page for all the requests.

Can anyone please help to identify and solve the problem!

```
namespace MyRequirement
{

    public class MyAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        readonly string allowedRoles;
        public MyAuthorizeAttribute(string allowedRoles)
        {
            this.allowedRoles = allowedRoles;
        }

        public System.Collections.Generic.List<string> AllowedRoles
        {
            get
            {
                return this.allowedRoles.Split(',').ToList();
            }
        }

        private bool AuthorizeRole(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            var context = filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext;
            PnLUserDetails userDetails = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["PnLUserDetails"] as PnLUserDetails;
            string loggedInUserRole = userDetails.Role;
            if (AllowedRoles.Contains(loggedInUserRole))
                return true;
            return false;
        }

        public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
            if (filterContext == null)
                throw new ArgumentException("filterContext");
            bool authStatus = AuthorizeRole(filterContext);
            if(!authStatus)
            {
                filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the call to

```
base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
```

Change the code like this

```
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        // This line is not needed, you are handling the authorization
        // This is the line that will give you the unauthorized access by default
        // base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
        if (filterContext == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("filterContext");
        bool authStatus = AuthorizeRole(filterContext);
        if(!authStatus)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
            return;
        }
    }
```